# Directive's $watch function not catching a variable in it's scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The javascript:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('RootCntr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.openedShelf = false;

    console.log('controller', $scope.openedShelf);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.openedShelf = true;
        console.log('controller', $scope.openedShelf);
    }, 2000);
});

App.directive('shelf', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'open': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('linked');

            scope.$watch('open', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log(newVal);
                if (newVal) {
                    console.log(true, newVal);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

The HTML:

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="RootCntr">
        <shelf open='openedShelf'></shelf>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I change the value of `openedShelf` in `RootCntr` the directive isn't catching the update with it's watch statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because setTimeout doesn't do an $apply, a $digest never happens and watchers are never called. Inject $timeout into your controller and use $timeout instead of setTimeout, just as you used setTimeout. $timeout is provided by angular and it always forces a $digest to occur.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.openedShelf = true;
    console.log('controller', $scope.openedShelf);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Great thanks.  Didn't know there was a separate $timeout function for angular.

Comment: Just FYI, there is a 3rd (optional) argument to $timeout called `invokeApply`.  When set to `false` it does not call $apply.  So we have control over whether a digest cycle executes or not with $timeout.